# Create matrix of maps

Tags: java, matrix, dictionary

I'm trying to make a matrix which has a Map in every cell, I can't get it to work, I've done this so far:

```
int mesos = h.getMesFinal() - h.getMesFinal();
Map<Integer, Doctor> [][] cal = new Map<Integer, Doctor> [30][mesos];
```

But it shows generic array creation alert.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an array of generic types.

You basically have 2 options:

1. Create a class `MyMap` that just wraps `Map<Integer, Doctor>` and use `MyMap[][]`
2. Use `ArrayList` (or any other structure) instead of arrays

To answer the comment, here is how you can do:

```
List<List<Map<Integer, Doctor>>> cal = new ArrayList<>(30);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
    cal.add(new ArrayList<Map<Integer, Doctor>>(mesos));
}
```

Comment: I guess for my purposes the second is the option that suits me the best, could you give me an example of how I should do it?

Comment: This looks really complicated, how can I access the elements of this array? I want to access for example `cal[1][2]` element which is a Map.

Comment: So you can do ``call.get(1).get(2)``.